# How to implement this rspec snippets

Tags: ruby, rspec

I would like to know what happened behind this snippet

How Ruby implements this syntax ?

```
feature "Course" do DO_SOMETHING end

scenario "A Course without name should not be accepted" do
end
```

Please give me some concrete direction or example

```
feature "Course" do

  let(:school) {School.make!}

  context "Logged in" do
    before(:each) do
      switch_to_subdomain(school)
    end

    context "In the new course form" do
      before(:each) do
        click_link("Courses")
        click_link("New course")
      end

      scenario "New course" do               
      end

      scenario "A Course without name should not be accepted" do
      end

      scenario "A new course should not be created if there is another one with the same name in the same school" do
      end
    end
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ruby, you can pass a block as the last parameter to a method, which can then either call it using `yield`, or treat it as an explicit variable, moving it around etc.

```
def scenario(name)
  puts name
  if block_given?
    yield
  end
end

def feature(name, &block)
  puts name
  if block_given?
    scenario("called from feature", &block)
  end
end

scenario("test") do puts "this" end
# => test
# => this

feature("test") do puts "this" end
# => test
# => called from feature
# => this
```

Also, since parentheses are optional in ruby, you can drop them receiving this syntax:

```
scenario "test" do
  puts "this"
end
# => test
# => this

feature "test" do 
   puts "this"
end
# => test
# => called from feature
# => this
```